# Moving from hard-coded to SOLID principles in PHP

Tags: oop, solid-principles

I am actually reading theory about clean code and SOLID principles. I know understand well that we should program to an interface and not to an implementation.

So, I actually try to apply those principles to a little part of my code. I would like to have your advice or point of view so I can know if I am going in the good direction. I'll show you my previous code and my actual so you can visualize the evolution.

To start, i had a method in my controller to check some requirements for every step of an order process (4 steps that the user have to follow in the right order => 1 then 2 then 3 and then 4)

This is my old code :

```
    private function isAuthorizedStep($stepNumber)
    {
        $isStepAccessAuthorized = TRUE;

        switch($stepNumber) {
            case self::ORDER_STEP_TWO: // ORDER_STEP_TWO = 2
                if (!($_SESSION['actualOrderStep'] >= ORDER_STEP_ONE)) {
                    $isStepAccessAuthorized = FALSE;
                }
                break;

            case self::ORDER_STEP_THREE:
                if (!($_SESSION['actualOrderStep'] >= ORDER_STEP_TWO)) {
                    $isStepAccessAuthorized = FALSE;
                }
                break;

            ...
        }

        return $isStepAccessAuthorized;
    }

    public function orderStepTwo()
    {
        if ($this->isAuthorizedStep(self::ORDER_STEP_TWO) {
            return;
        }

        ... // do some stuff

        // after all the verifications: 
        $_SESSION['actualOrderStep'] = ORDER_STEP_TWO
    }
```

Trying to fit to SOLID principles, I splited my code following this logic:

- Extracting hard-coded logic from controllers to put it in classes (reusability)
- Using Dependency Injection and abstraction

```
    interface RuleInterface {
        public function matches($int);
    }

    class StepAccessControl
    {
       protected $rules;

       public function __construct(array $rules)
       {
           foreach($rules as $key => $rule) {
               $this->addRule($key, $rule);
           }
       }

       public isAccessGranted($actualOrderStep)
       {
           $isAccessGranted = TRUE;

           foreach($this->rules as $rule) {
               if (!$rule->matches($actualOrderStep) {
                   $isAccessGranted = FALSE;
               }
           }

           return $isAccessGranted;
       }

       public function addRule($key, RuleInterface $rule)
       {
           $this->rules[$key] = $rule;
       }
    }

    class OrderStepTwoRule implements RuleInterface
    {
        public function matches($actualStep)
        {
            $matches = TRUE;

            if (!($actualStep >= 1)) {
                $isStepAccessAuthorized = FALSE;
            }

            return $matches;
        }
    }

    class StepAccessControlFactory
    {
        public function build($stepNumber)
        {
            if ($stepNumber == 1) {
                ...
            } elseif ($stepNumber == 2) {
                $orderStepTwoRule = new OrderStepTwoRule();
                return new StepAcessControl($orderStepTwoRule);
            }...
        }
    }
```

and then in the controller :

```
    public function stepTwoAction()
    {
        $stepAccessControlFactory = new StepAccessControlFactory();
        $stepTwoAccessControl = $stepAccessControlFactory(2);

        if (!$stepTwoAccessControl->isAccesGranted($_SESSION['actualOrderStep'])) {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

**I would like to know if I get the spirit and if I am on the good way :)**

Comment: Just one advice...don't go full `SOLID`...some of this principles are really hard to implement(LSP for example)...what I mean is, do not get all that info per se; made your own assumptions and try to read about how a lot of people try to simplify those principles in a more manageable way....

Comment: Ok, il'll keep this fact in my mind.

Comment: Is there someone who can just tell me if I am in the good direction ? :)

Comment: I think that you are on the good track...can I ask you why are you trying to go `SOLID` on php, instead of another more OOP programming  and traditional language, like `Java` or `C#`?

Comment: Also if you just want a review of your code, you can post it on codereview

Comment: You may try to have more meaningful names. like in place of stepOne and stepTwo, try something like isAccountActive() and isUserAllowed(). You have used Factory method, try to create an interface and implement it. If else in creation of objects is bad code smell. For code examples on SOLID principles, have a look on - https://bootsity.com/php/understanding-the-solid-principles-of-software-engineering